# Magento 2 - Type error: require is not a function for admin grid in custom page with custom tab

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento2

I am trying to load a grid to a tab on a custom page in Mangento 2 admin. The grid is rendered beautifully but `js` seems to be uninitialized after the ajax reload fetches it from controller. The grid is not responsive at all. Browser console displays "Type Error: require is not a function", but I don't understand how to initialize js for the grid after ajax.

My code (skipping boilerplate e.g. `registration.php`, `composer.json`, `etc/module.xml`, `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`):

/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Offers/Edit.php

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Offers;

  class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
    
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
         return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
?>
```

/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layouts/module_offers_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Angebot
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer\Edit\Tabs"
                name="vendor_module_offer.edit.tabs"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer\Edit"
                name="vendor_module_offer.edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Offer/Edit.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;

class Edit extends Container{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'module_offer_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Module';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_offer';
        parent::_construct();
        $this->buttonList->remove('save');
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return __('Offer');
    }

    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

}
```

/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Offer/Edit/Tabs.php

```
<?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer\Edit;

   use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs as WidgetTabs;

   class Tabs extends WidgetTabs{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('offer_edit_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Angebot'));
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab(
            'Produkte',
            [
                'label' => __('Products'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('module/*/products', ['_current' => true]),
                'class' => 'ajax'
            ]
        );
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

This is all just setup for the tabs to display on the page with path `.../admin/module/offers/edit/ID`. Now, to fill the tab with products I load the grid with this:

/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Offers/Products.php

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Offers;

  class Products extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
         return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
?>
```

/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/module_offers_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer\Edit\Tab\View\Products" name="offer.edit.tab.product"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Offer/Edit/Tab/View/Products.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Offer\Edit\Tab\View;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\OfferItemFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('offer_view_products_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('offer_item_stock_id', 'desc');
        $this->setSortable(true);
        $this->setPagerVisibility(true);
        $this->setFilterVisibility(true);
    }

    protected function _preparePage()
    {
        $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('offer_item_stock_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('stock_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'customize',
            [
                'label' => __('Anpassen (ToDo)'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('test/test/test')
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
     protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'offer_item_stock_id',
            ['header' => __('Stock ID'), 'index' => 'offer_item_stock_id', 'type' => 'number', 'width' => '50px']
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getHeadersVisibility()
    {
        return $this->getCollection()->getSize() >= 0;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('test/test/test');
    }
}
```

So my question is how to initialize js for the grid after ajax load.